# Submit downloads cgi instead of redirecting to web page

Tags: html, c, cgi

I have a web page for login. When I press the Submit button it is supposed to check user name and password and then if successful it should redirect me to a new web page or even if unsuccessful it should redirect me to another web page. I am using POST in my form and using a .c file to check the user name and password which will printf the new web pages for both successful login and unsuccessful login. The problem I am having is that when I press Submit it tries to download my .cgi file and asks permission to save it instead of redirecting to my new web pages. Is anything wrong with my HTML file or is there something wrong with my .c file. What might be the problem and what can I do to fix it? I am attaching my part of the c file thats supposed to print the new web page.

```
  printf("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\n\n");
  int c;
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("Success.txt", "r");
  if (file) {
  while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
            putchar(c);
            fclose(file);
            }
```

//Here I open a txt file that contains all my info(tags) for the html page that needs to be printed and then I use putchar to print everything.

Comment: Instead of a standard HTML page with status code 200 you should answer with code 302 and supply an URL for redirection. See examples e.g. here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx

Comment: Perhaps your web server is not configured to execute CGI from the specific directory you are attempting to execute it from (or perhaps the file is not flagged appropriately to be executed).  Are you using Apache, or some other web server?

Comment: Yes I am using Apache and my university web server is configured to execute CGI from my public_html directory